# Xamarin For Visual Studio Schema Issues

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

After having upgraded Xamarin for my Visual Studio 2015 installation, I have been having several issues. I have had to upgrade SDK (run as administrator), upgrade java, delete the .vs folder, run VS as administrator, delete cache, etc. After having done these things I have been able to develop normally. Now today I booted up and have been having issues with xaml. At first, the layout view wouldn't load. Then the schema wasn't loading in the source view.

I believe I have solved my issues by moving the project folders to a local drive rather than a share on my host.

Hope this helps others.

Here are a few errors to help those whom are searching:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning       Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...
>
> Cannot resolve the 'schemaLocation' attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have solved my issues by moving the project folders to a local drive rather than a share on my host.